# Desativar Bootstrap Collapse após primeiro clique

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, collapse

Tenho uma página, na qual apliquei a classe bootstrap collapse, onde ao clicar ele expande uma determinada área e a página rola até aquela parte do site. Quero que, ao clicar e expandir essa área, o botão perca essa funcionalidade, ou seja, quando expandido, mesmo o usuário clicando novamente no botão, a área permaneça aberta e não feche. Tem como fazer isso em css ou somente m javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O collapse do bootstrap tem uma série de eventos e você pode usa-los para evitar ficar fazendo bind e unbind de eventos de click e etc.

```
$('.panel').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Esse código previne que um painel aberto seja fechado.

Também existem esses eventos

> **show.bs.collapse**  Occurs when the collapsible element is about to be
>   shown
>
> **shown.bs.collapse**     Occurs when the collapsible element is fully shown
>   (after CSS transitions have completed)
>
> **hide.bs.collapse**  Occurs when the collapsible element is about to be
>   hidden
>
> **hidden.bs.collapse**    Occurs when the collapsible element is fully
>   hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)

Comment: A solução é somente em javascript mesmo? não existe uma classe onde eu possa chamar esse comando?

Comment: @WelkerZigante como assim classe?

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de colocar as tags HTML (data-toggle="collapse" e "data-target") no botão que mostra o seu componente, mostre-o pelo js e depois desabilite o clique no botão:

```
$('#meu-botao').click(function(){

    $('#element-alvo-do-collapse').collapse('show');
    $('#meu-botao').unbind('click')

});
```